# IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is null

Tags: .net-core

I'm using DotNet 5.0, and even though I register `HttpContextAccessor` in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` whenever I try to reach it inside the code, IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is **always** null.

This is my Startup.cs file's ConfigureServices Method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
    var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
    this.Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json").Build();
    
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
    {
        options.AddAspNetCore();
    });
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

And this is the Configure method of the same file:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseSimpleInjector(container);

    container.Verify();
}
```

And also I'm using **hangfire**, but whenever a job gets triggered I cannot reach HttpContextAccessor through dependency injection. It is always null.

For example this is one of my business layer files:

```
public class FooService
{

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public FooService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAcessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public DoSomething()
    {
        var tryoutVar = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }

}
```

The `tryoutVar` variable is set to null, always.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try to inject the service with asp.net core like services.AddTransient<FooService>().
I think it might be due to your simple injector.

Comment: As is stated in this documentation : https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html.
You might need to add: AddControllerActivation

Comment: @Cristian-ȘtefănițăScăueru I already had the dependency injection of FooService, and even after AddControllerActivation() the problem still exists.